# Are Memory Leak's shrinking slots affected by Autoroll?

Tags: dicey-dungeons

When [Memory Leak](https://diceydungeons.fandom.com/wiki/Memory_Leak) is equipped, the usable slots shrink on each roll. This means the maximum dice value you can use with the equipment lowers by one each time you roll a dice. (First roll drops max to 5, second to max 4, etc.)

How is Memory Leak's max value affected when using the [Robot's Autoroll ability](https://diceydungeons.fandom.com/wiki/Robot#Limit_Break:)? Do the dice generated with Autoroll count against the max slot value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, each dice generated by Autoroll will lower the max value of Memory Leak by 1. Tested myself with an autoroll that generated four dice and lowered Memory Leak's max value to 2.